# Is there any way to know the bytes that have been sent/received by serial port in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, port, communication, tty

I need to know the quantity of bytes that are sent or received in a certain time via serial port, in bash. It may be something similar to /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes in ethernet. How can I get this information?

I am making a service that sends some data to the user. One field is the sent and transmitted bytes by the serial and the ethernet interfaces. In the second case it is easy to get the information, but in the serial case I am not able to find how. This is meant to work in an embedded system where it is nos easy to add new hardware nor software (I mean, I cannot use apt-get nor downloading a sniffer for linux).

I assume there is not such an easy solution. I have not seen any command that could help me. The only solution I have thought is directing the data to a flase port where a process counts the bytes and then redirects them to the real serial port. But there may be a better solution.

Comment: You could maybe try Googling `RS-232 Snooping` or `RS-232 Sniffer` https://store.chipkin.com/articles/rs232-how-can-i-do-serial-port-sniffing-snooping-through-rs232/

Comment: Looks like a lowly Raspberry Pi could do it too... https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=84502

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I forgot to say that this is meant to work in an embedded system where it is nos easy to add new hardware nor software (I mean, I cannot use apt-get nor downloading a sniffer for linux). I am going to edit the message to add this point.